# Does zkteco have a web API?

Tags: api, zkteco

I am trying to build a java application which will fetch the data of **zkteco biometric**.

Does **zkteco** have a built-in API ?

If not, how can I connect to **zkteco** to a java app?

Comment: I've already read the documentation of zkteco and downloaded the sdk of it. But it confuses me since im not be able to run the sdk....

Comment: one year later what was the solution ?

Comment: @ChiKaLiO I converted my app to c# https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1104538/Csharp-ZKTeco-Biometric-Device-Getting-Started

Answer (score 4):

Zkteco biometric offers two sector of the products.

- ZkTeco Attendance and AccessControl Systems
- ZkTeco Fingerprint Scanners

They can be integrated with the desktop/web based application over USB or TCP/IP. It is an intranet application. The SDK for the integration can be downloaded from [Biometric SDK Download Center](https://www.zkteco.com/en/download_catgory.html).They can also be integrated with the web based application over HTTP. It is an internet application. The API is available [Biometric Attendance Web API](http://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html) and [Web API for Fingerprint Scanner](http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html). All the devices do not support the HTTP communication. So, to make sure if your device supports the HTTP communication, you may need to get your device verified at [ZkTeco Device Verification for Web API](http://developer.camsunit.com)

Comment: What is the relation between ZkTeco and this site you are redirecting people: https://camsunit.com/ ?

Comment: cams is the api parter for zkteco devices. More information can be found at https://camsunit.com/product/cams-protocol-update-for-enabling-api-to-biometric-attendance-system.html